# Children's game about a hotel for fantasy creatures

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I remember an old computer game that seemed to be geared towards children. It was about managing a hotel that would be visited by fantasy creatures. The goal is to ensure that all of the guests are accommodated and satisfied. One of the possible guests that you could get is a group of vampires, which must be given a double-room and have fancy demands. Does anyone know what game this is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Haunted Domains](https://www.utomik.com/games/haunted-domains) possibly?

[image: Haunted Domains]

> Manage a haunted hotel for comical creatures of the night in Haunted Domains, a whimsical challenge that will have you howling with delight. It's the middle of the night and Sheila just received a call from her grandfather to come help him run his establishment. Her grandfather is rather cryptic as to the types of guests she'll be helping out with, but nevertheless she's on her way.
>
> - meet vampires, witches, ghosts and more in this ghoulish time management escapade
> - play 50 sidesplitting levels in five hair-raising locations
> - purchase magical upgrades, decorate hotels, and enlist the help of Igor
> - enjoy two game modes, monstrous achievements, and a special Halloween-style garden

I have never played it, but the description does seem to match. The game was developed by *Alawar Entertainment*, though their web site no longer has any mention of it. However I did find a trailer for the game on YouTube: